# How do I fix this SQL invalid group function error?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure why my code isn't working and I get an error for an invalid group function.

```
SELECT staffNo, salary FROM dreamhome.Staff WHERE(AVG(salary) >= AVG(salary) * 1.5);
```

Comment: You should no use group by functions in where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest the following query:

```
SELECT staffNo, salary
FROM dreamhome.Staff
WHERE salary >= (SELECT 1.5*AVG(salary) FROM dreamhome.Staff);
```

This would return every staff member whose salary is more than 50% greater than the average salary in the entire table.